# Can't launch web app for interactive dashboard

Tags: python, bokeh, panel, dashboard

I am trying to panel serve to launch web app dashboard, but only error below shows in the terminal. Is there anyone know what's problem and how to fix it, Thanks!

(co2_dashboard) jiehuilin@Jiehuis-MBP co2_dashboard % panel serve co2_dashboard.ipynb
2023-06-26 20:59:21,243 Starting Bokeh server version 3.1.1 (running on Tornado 6.3.2)
2023-06-26 20:59:21,244 User authentication hooks NOT provided (default user enabled)
2023-06-26 20:59:21,246 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/co2_dashboard
2023-06-26 20:59:21,246 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 3367

Best Regards

Comment: To me it looks like it is working. To you try to open `http://localhost:5006/co2_dashboard` in a browser? If there is an error, could you please add the traceback or error message to your post?

Comment: It works now, Thanks so much! Only one problem now is that the dashboard response slow when I move around glider, or radio button...

Comment: @J Lin, glad to here that it is working. The speed of your project depends on the data you want to display. Can't help you, because I don't know anything about it.